# Jar file for S40 series

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-me

I am developing a java app for nokia s40 mobiles. My jar file increases more than 1 mb.
When i installed my app on device it say

"Too large file to install"

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Then may be you can compress image size with reducing the quality of image may be

Comment: On that point @JigarJoshi brought up, try not to use bitmaps and use JPEGs with suitable compression. If you include third party libraries, compress them too.

Comment: how to compress the third party librariesbecause i use couple of them floggy and LWUIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) to shrink your .Jar file.

It's Configuration is very easy. Just configure it in your Wireless Toolkit and when you create .Jar file create it with "Create Obfuscated Package" option from Project Menu's Package Option.

It will reduce size of your .Jar file.

Comment: actually i am using LWUIT an external jar which is round about 635kb.how can i compress it